# Return observable from async function

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, async-await, observable

**TLDR;** I have a Promise `collection().add()` which resolves to an object `DocumentReference` with a listener function `onSnapshot()` that emits data.

I need to return an Observable which, upon subscription, calls the Promise, subscribes to the listener function on the resolved object, and broadcasts the values from the listener to `subscriber.next()`

**Context:**
I am trying to declare a function that creates a Firestore document, then returns an Observable with the document data, using the `onSnapshot()` function on its DocumentReference returned by `collection().add()`.

Based on: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/f6972433dea48bf1d342a6e4ef7f955dff341837/demo-ng/app/item/items.component.ts#L175-L185

```
async create(project) {
    const ref = await this.db.collection('projects').add(project);
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
        ref.onSnapshot(doc => {
            // ...
            subscriber.next(doc.data());
        });
    });
}
```

**Current behaviour:**`async/await` always returns a Promise, I need the function to return an observable.

**Expected:** I need a slice of data from the `ref.onSnapshot()` callback, in this case `doc.data()`, to use it in my template, e.g.

```
// ... 

this.service.create(project).subscribe(project => console.log(project));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly the problem is with your code? Do you have any error messages that pop up? How do you consume the `create` method? What's the expected behaviour vs. the actual behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your implementation `create` returns a promise, since as you pointed out it needs to work `async`. If this is a fact then you have to modify the context calling `create`: simply make the calling function `async` as well and add `await` before the call to `create`: `await create(...)`.

As an alternative, if you want to return an observable no matter what, you have to stop `await`ing the `db.collection().add()` and remove the `async` before `create`. Then you can return the observable directly and inside the `.then` function of `db.collection().add()` you could update the observable with `doc.data()`:

```
create(project) {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
        this.db.collection('projects').add(project)
           .then(ref => {
                ref.onSnapshot(doc => {
                    // ...
                    subscriber.next(doc.data());
                });
           });
    });
}
```

Note that `await` is just one way to handle a `Promise`. The more classical way is attaching a callback to its `.then`. Note that `.then` again returns a `Promise` which again has a `.then` and so on - this is how `Promise`s are defined.

Comment: Yup the latter works for me, simple solution thank you.

Comment: You could also just make the inner function async `return new Observable(async subscriber => {`

Comment: That would work as well, yes. Personally I feel it's cleaner not to return a `Promise` from a callback if it is not used, but both are valid solutions.